# SQL Query-calculating last week data for an ordinary calendar year

Tags: sql-server, date

I have to retrieve the last week data from a table.
i am using the following condition.

```
@prmCurrent_Year=Datepart(year,getdate())

 last_week=case when Datepart(week,col_name)=1 
                then 52 
                else Datepart(week,col_name)-1 and   
                     year_num=case 
                              when Datepart(week,col_name)=1 
                              then @prmCurrent_Year-1 
                              else @prmCurrent_ Year
```

will this work properly or is there any other better query for this???

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might suffice:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE MyDate BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, -1, GetDate()) AND GetDate()
```

DateAdd reference on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx